# How to pass std::function as an argument to a mocked method in gmock?

Tags: c++, googletest, googlemock

I am getting a runtime error when trying to pass an `std:function` as an argument to a mocked method inside `EXPECT_CALL`.
I wish to verify that `Bar` is called with `callback` as an argument.

Code:

```
#include <gtest/gtest.h>
#include <gmock/gmock.h>

class Foo {
public:
    virtual void Bar(const std::function<void (const std::string &name)> &callback) = 0;
};

class MockFoo : public Foo {
public:
    MOCK_METHOD(void, Bar, (const std::function<void (const std::string &name)> &callback));
};

TEST(FooBarTest, callback) {
    MockFoo foo;

    const std::function<void(const std::string &name)> callback;

    EXPECT_CALL(foo, Bar(callback)).Times(1);

    foo.Bar(callback);
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    testing::InitGoogleTest(&argc, argv);
    return RUN_ALL_TESTS();
}
```

An error is produced at runtime:

```
/usr/local/include/gtest/gtest-matchers.h:211:60: error: no match for ‘operator==’ (operand types are ‘const std::function<void(const std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>&)>’ and ‘const std::function<void(const std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>&)>’)
   bool operator()(const A& a, const B& b) const { return a == b; }
```

Answer (score 2):

There are pre-defined `ACTIONS` that you could use for this purpose. Your `EXPECT_CALL` would look something like:

```
using namespace testing; // for brevity

TEST(FooBarTest, callback) {
    MockFoo foo;

    const std::function<void(const std::string &name)> callback;

    EXPECT_CALL(foo, Bar(_)).WillOnce(Invoke(callback));

    foo.Bar(callback);
}
```

As pointed out by @IanGralinski, there's no matcher for `std::function`, so you can use any matcher for the call (i.e. `_`).

However, this is not how I would use gmock here - why mocking `Foo` if you use it directly? Usually mocks are used when you test interactions of your (real) class with other classes (mocked). So in your example: `Foo` could be mocked by `MockFoo` and used by some other class (real one), using dependency injection.

On a side note, remember to add virtual destructor to `Foo` if the object derived from `Foo` is to be deleted by pointer to `Foo` (this would be UB without virtual dtor).

Comment: I assume the question uses the mock directly only to keep the example minimal, since that piece isn't the point of the question.

Comment: Yep, I missed the need to invoke the argument to the mock :(. I have removed my answer since this one shows how to do what I was trying to do, but is actually correct.

Comment: As mentioned by @aschepler, this is just a minimal example. In the real application a mock is needed. In this example I wish to verify with EXPECT_CALL that Bar is invoked with callback as an argument. Verifying that callback was invoked is not the goal here.

Answer (score 1):

The arguments to the method named in an `EXPECT_CALL` are actually matchers. When you just provide a value (something which is not already a gmock `Matcher<T>` type), that implies an `Eq` matcher. So `EXPECT_CALL(foo, Bar(callback))` really means `EXPECT_CALL(foo, Bar(Eq(callback)))`. The trouble is, `std::function` does not provide an `operator==` for comparing two functions. Its type-erasure properties mean an equality test would be impossible to implement in general, plus of course some of the class functor types it might wrap around won't have their own `operator==` either.

But it is possible to test whether a `std::function` contains a very specific object. If you don't want to just ignore the argument by expecting `Bar(_)`, here's an idea for identifying whether a `std::function` is a specific dummy function.

First, create a callable class which we'll use to initialize the `std::function` object. I'll also have its `operator()` call a mock method, which is not needed when it's just passed to a mock function, but this will make it possible to use the same `std::function` in different contexts, or set expectations before one real function which will both call it directly and pass it to a mocked interface.

```
template <typename FuncT> class DummyFunction; // undefined

template <typename RetType, typename... ArgTypes>
class DummyFunction<RetType(ArgTypes...)> {
public:
    constexpr DummyFunction() : DummyFunction(0) {}
    explicit constexpr DummyFunction(int key) : m_key(key) {}
    constexpr DummyFunction(const DummyFunction& f) : m_key(f.m_key) {}
    constexpr int key() const { return m_key; }

    MOCK_METHOD(RetType, doCall, (ArgTypes...));

    RetType operator()(ArgTypes... args)
    { return doCall(std::forward<ArgTypes>(args)...); }

    friend constexpr bool operator==(const DummyFunction& f1, const DummyFunction& f2)
    { return f1.m_key == f2.m_key; }
    friend constexpr bool operator!=(const DummyFunction& f1, const DummyFunction& f2)
    { return !(f1 == f2); }
    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const DummyFunction& f)
    { return os << "DummyFunction(" << f.m_key << ")"; }

private:
    int m_key;
};
```

Then a gmock Matcher to test whether a `std::function` contains a `DummyFunction` object with the exact same function type as template parameter and the same key as a given `DummyFunction` object could look like this. Since it's possible to convert one type of `std::function` to another as long as the parameter types and return types convert correctly (or the return type changes to `void`), I made it a "polymorphic" matcher which accepts any `std::function` specialization for testing.

```
template <class DummyFuncType>
class IsDummyFunctionTester {
public:
    explicit constexpr IsDummyFunctionTester(int key) : m_key(key) {}

    // The three member functions required for gmock "PolymorphicMatcher":
    template <typename FuncType>
    bool MatchAndExplain(const std::function<FuncType>& f,
                         ::testing::MatchResultListener* listener) const {
        bool type_ok = f.target_type() == typeid(DummyFuncType);
        if (type_ok) {
            int f_key = f.template target<DummyFuncType>()->key();
            if (f_key == m_key) return true;
            *listener << "std::function contains DummyFunction(" << m_key << ")";
        } else if (!f) {
            *listener << "std::function is empty";
        } else {
            // Note name() is implementation dependent. For g++/clang it's mangled.
            *listener << "std::function target's type_info::name() is "
                      << f.target_type().name();
        }
        return false;
    }

    void DescribeTo(std::ostream* os) const
    { *os << "is a DummyFunction(" << m_key << ")"; }
    void DescribeNegationTo(std::ostream* os) const
    { *os << "is not a DummyFunction(" << m_key << ")"; }

private:
    int m_key;
};
template <typename FuncType>
decltype(auto) StdFuncIsDummyFunc(const DummyFunction<FuncType>& f) {
    return ::testing::MakePolymorphicMatcher(
        IsDummyFunctionTester<DummyFunction<FuncType>>(f.key()));
}
```

So finally, you can do:

```
TEST(FooBarTest, callback) {
    MockFoo foo;

    const DummyFunction<void(const std::string &name)> callback;

    EXPECT_CALL(foo, Bar(StdFuncIsDummyFunc(callback))).Times(1);

    foo.Bar(callback);
}
```

If you have just one `DummyFunction`, or if exactly which `DummyFunction` is which isn't important for the test, you can just use the default "key" of zero like above. Otherwise, you can specify unique keys for each distinct dummy callback.